# Why does the explicit syntax for creating Tuples only allow AnyRefs as type annotations?

Tags: scala, types, singleton, tuples

This code works:

```
scala> val x = ""
x: java.lang.String = ""

scala> Tuple2[x.type, x.type](x,x)
res5: (x.type, x.type) = ("","")
```

This one doesn't:

```
scala> val y = 0
y: Int = 0

scala> Tuple2[y.type, y.type](y,y)
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : y.type (with underlying type Int)
 required: AnyRef
Note: an implicit exists from scala.Int => java.lang.Integer, but
methods inherited from Object are rendered ambiguous.  This is to avoid
a blanket implicit which would convert any scala.Int to any AnyRef.
You may wish to use a type ascription: `x: java.lang.Integer`.
              Tuple2[y.type, y.type](y,y)
                     ^
```

As well as this one:

```
scala> val z = ()
z: Unit = ()

scala> Tuple2[z.type, z.type](z,z)
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : z.type (with underlying type Unit)
 required: AnyRef
Note: Unit is not implicitly converted to AnyRef.  You can safely
pattern match `x: AnyRef` or cast `x.asInstanceOf[AnyRef]` to do so.
              Tuple2[z.type, z.type](z,z)
                     ^
```

The language specification says

> A singleton type is of the form p.type, where p is a path pointing to
>   a value expected to conform (§6.1) to scala.AnyRef.

What's the rationale behind that and would it make sense to lift that restriction like it recently happened with `0.getClass`?

Comment: As shown by your example, it has absolutely nothing to do with tuple. The point is that you cannot do .type on a value type. I don't know whether that would be feasible, and wonder when it could be useful.

Comment: Isn't that pretty much what I cited (§6.1) and wondered what's the rationale behind it?

Comment: Indeed your question ends so. The title (and your example) mentions tuple however.

Comment: since there is type erasure on the JVM I wouldn't recomment to use .type at all. Use generics if you want to be flexible with types.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see on [Scala class hierarchy](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/71?size=_original) `Int`, `Unit`, `Boolean` (and others) are not subclasses of AnyRef, because they are translated into java `int`, `void`, `boolean` and so on, witch are not subclasses of `Object`.

Comment: But why does this restriction exist?